# syntax checker (linter) for Jenkins scripted pipeline file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I want to check the syntax of the Jenkinsfile  (**"SCRIPTED pipeline file"**,  *not declarative pipeline*) in my machine before committing in version control system.
Is there any tool available. All the tools I checked are supporting declarative syntax only.

Comment: Indeed there is only a declarative syntax linter. If you wanted to do a scripted syntax linter, then I think your best bet would be to just to do a Groovy syntax linter.